# Error in executing 'send' on 'RTCDataChannel' simple-peer

Tags: javascript, webrtc, simple-peer

I am trying out webrtc using the library, simple-peer.
I am following this tutorial linked [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ieBtXwHvoNk) on opera browser.
I am facing this error when sending a small string of 'hello':

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'send' on 'RTCDataChannel': RTCDataChannel.readyState is not 'open' at Peer.send (http://127.0.0.1:9966/bundle.js:7011:19) at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (http://127.0.0.1:9966/bundle.js:22:14) send @ index.js:241 (anonymous) @ index.js:21
```

Here is my index.js:

```js
    var Peer = require('simple-peer')

    if (Peer.WEBRTC_SUPPORT) {
        console.log("Support");
        peer = new Peer({
            initiator: location.hash === '#1',
            trickle:true
        })
        peer.on('signal', function (data) {
            document.getElementById('yourId').value = JSON.stringify(data)
        })
        document.getElementById("connect").addEventListener('click', function () {
            var otherId = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('otherId').value)
            peer.signal(otherId)
        })
        peer.on('connect', function () {
            console.log("CONNECTED");
        })
        document.getElementById("send").addEventListener('click', function () {
            var message = document.getElementById("message_to_send").value
            peer.write(message)
        })
        peer.on("data", function (data) {
            console.log(data)
            document.getElementById("messages").textContent += data + "\n"
        })

    } else {
        console.log("No Support, Sorry");
    }
```

Changing 
`peer.send(data)`
to 
`peer.write(data)`
does to give any error, but nor does it send the data to the other browser

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. If useful to anybody:
I was using the opera browser, which blocked my IP address from "leaking". Switching to Chrome worked like a charm
See if your browser is blocking your IP address using this link:  [https://diafygi.github.io/webrtc-ips/](http://%20https://diafygi.github.io/webrtc-ips/)